# Tracking of field changes in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to keep track of the changes made in a field of a model. Let say it's posting_status. The choices are open and close. So I want to track when it changes to open from close and close from open.

For this I tried django-simple-history, but in this I can't see the last status. Means it gives the current status only with updated date. So I need to show the previous status too. What should I do?

One more thing I want to ask: If i delete some field and do migrate then what will be the effect? Please help me out. I'm stuck on the same from last many days. :(

```
class Job_posting(models.Model):                                                            user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,      blank=True)                                             
    POSTING_CHOICES = (                     
        ('O', 'Open'),                    
        ('P', 'Pause'),                   
        ('C', 'Close'),
    )                  
    OFFER_LETTER_CHOICES = (              
        ('YES', 'Yes'),                   
        ('NO', 'No'),
    )

    posting_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=POSTING_CHOICES)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, null=True, blank=True, default=None)                                                       

    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

I am checking by SQL command.

Comment: Please add some code to give a starting point for potential answers, because with a simple sample project, `django-simple-history` works as expected and gives me access to historic values of an example flag field for a simple model. From the data you are providing here, there is currently no way to guess where your problem is.

Comment: @dhke HEre is my code

Comment: @dhke : I just edited my question , please chk it and help me out :)

Comment: What does `post_obj.history.all()` yield for some existing `post_obj` in `Job_posting`? Because that's where your history should show up.

Comment: LET ME TRY ..JUST A MINUTE

Comment: CharField' object has no attribute 'history' .. giving error

Comment: You are trying to access `history` on the field. The history is a property of the whole model object, not of individual fields.

Answer (score 1):

`django-simple-history` should solve your problem.

```
POSTING_CHOICES = (                     
    ('O', 'Open'),                    
    ('P', 'Pause'),                   
    ('C', 'Close'),
)                  

class Job_posting(models.Model):
    posting_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=POSTING_CHOICES)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Testing:

```
# jp1 = Job_posting.objects.create(posting_status='O')
# jp1.posting_status = 'P'
# jp1.save()
# jp1.history.last().posting_status
u'O'
```

Note that `history` is a per-model and not a per-field state.

Comment: @skolsuper OP mentioned django-simple-history, so I thought to go with that. Doesn't hurt to know about signals, too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an unorthodox solution, but maybe make a clone of your model on the pre_save signal, then on the post_save signal check if there are any clones, check for differences, and then create history items for any changes. E.g.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    posting_status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # Using a CharField because your question doesn't make a lot of sense for a BooleanField, if it's changed and it's True then it was surely False before.

class Clone(BlogPost):
    blogpost_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

# You'll also need a place to store the histories:

class HistoryItem(models.Model):
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, related_name='posting_status_history')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    old_value = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    new_value = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# Then simple dirty checking of the field before and after it's saved

@receiver(pre_save, sender=BlogPost)
def create_clone(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
    created = kwargs.pop('created', False)
    if not created and instance is not None:
        old_instance = BlogPost.objects.get(id=instance.id)  # This is pre-save so the object in db will have old values
        Clone.objects.create(blogpost_id=instance.id, posting_status=old_instance.posting_status, commit=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
def check_changes(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
    created = kwargs.pop('created', False)
    if not created and instance is not None:
        old_instance = Clone.objects.filter(blogpost_id=instance.id)
        old_value = old_instance.posting_status
        new_value = instance.posting_status
        if old_value != new_value:
            HistoryItem.objects.create(blogpost=instance, old_value=old_value, new_value=new_value)
        old_instance.delete()  # Clear up the clone
```

After that your BlogPost items with changes will have a `posting_status_history` related object manager, which you can query with `blogpost.posting_status_history.all()`